# Fody.stamp timeout configuration

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, fody

We using Stamp.Fody package in some of our .NET projects and they sometimes intermittently fail Build with the following error: `Fody: Failed to apply product version to Win32 resources in 1 second.` Apparently 1 second is a default timeout and it causes Build to fail if verpatch exceeds that timeout. Looks like that timeout is also configurable : [this feature was added to package](https://github.com/yura-yaroshevich/Stamp/commit/d49bfa1a6f6a0e5ad8f6200465496f4a10b9cbc2). The question is how do you configure/increase timeout?

Comment: can you also verify that the below answer works for you?

Comment: @Tamas - thanks so much for the reply. Sorry on vacation. Will try next week and let you know.

Comment: @Tamas - just tried it and it works. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It [seems](https://github.com/Fody/Stamp/blob/2a11b2ec5217da61baca34e71c7a2c06c0c4f774/Fody/ModuleWeaver.cs#L148) that you can set this through the config attributes. So, try the following in your FodyWeavers.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
  <Stamp VerPatchWaitTimeoutInMilliseconds="2000" />
</Weavers>
```